# Angularjs: define different css for each page in menu

Tags: css, angularjs

I know this might be a silly question but Im new to the concept of Angularjs, i have a menu with different pages and im trying to combine the CSS to my pages, but each page has a diffrent CSS than the other

```
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'mainController'
    }) 

    .state('app.Page1', {
        url: '/Page1',
        views: { 
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/Page1.html'
            }},
        controller: 'mainController'        
    })

    .state('app.Page2', {
        url: '/Page2',
        views: { 
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/Page2.html'
            }},
        controller: 'mainController'

    });
```

where Page1 has a diffrent CSS than Page2 , i can not define then in the index.html because they contain same classes. any idea how to define CSS for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PathToYourCSS" media="all" property="stylesheet"/>
```

In `templates/Page1.html` and `templates/Page2.html` and You will be fine.

Comment: i tried this earlier, but when ever i access page1 and then page2 the 2 css classes will be mixed together.

Comment: What version of angular are You using?

Comment: Strange, it is working fine for me [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i16J2btuSdsXtGtCHxi1?p=preview). Can You provide demo in plunker? And why not to switch ti angular 1.4 and angular-router?

Comment: i switch it to angularjs 1.5 and it worked fine ! thank you so much for your help :)